# Print debugger messages in Visual Studio without modifying code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I really like how gdb allows me to script a routine for breakpoints using the `command` command. Often times, I add print statements to just print a message, and I like how all of this works without modifying the source file.

I had to use Visual Studio and I found out that the way to insert debug print statements is using `OutputDebugString`. But, I don't like how I need to modify my source code in order to debug. Is there a way to print debug messages in VS like in gdb, i.e. without modifying source.

Also, how does the VC compiler process the `OutputDebugString` call? Does it actually compile that line in the program's assembly? Do I need to compile my code if the only change I made is to add a call to `OutputDebugString`?

Comment: you can always use macros for debug builds like `#ifdef _DEBUG OutputDebugString() #endif ` so that when you're compiling on release mode none of this functions will actually compile and will be left out of the program. And yes, the function generates assembly(generated machine) code. The lasts question I don't fully understand, I think you need to compile your code if you make ANY changes to it...

Comment: @ViniyoShouta Thank you, that answers everything.

Comment: @ViniyoShouta Is it unreasonable to be annoyed by this? I wonder why MS did it this way, the gdb way seems so much better.

Comment: Well it's actually great if you need to output a lot of stuff when debugging, on loops for example, if you had to set a breakpoint and check the values of things every single time the loop runs that'd be terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for Visual Studio **tracepoints**.

I haven't used them, but they appear to be [well documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7(v=VS.80).aspx).

A tracepoint can print a message, and doesn't involve modifying your source code.